# Can I save data retrieved from API to a Data Studio dashboard?

Tags: looker-studio

I've connected a custom API to my Data Studio page that shows the total number of registrations to my website in real-time.
Is there a way to "save" every day this number into a Data Studio table/graph or an external Spreadsheet?
I can't (unfortunately) do this from the API directly for many tech/security reasons.

Thanks for your precious help, as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can consume your API directly, you can easily create a [Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/build) to do so.

But, if this is not an option for whatever reason, you'll need an [ETL solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load).  In short, you basically need some utility to run daily basis to populate your Spreadsheet.

I would recommend using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to connect to your API, parse the data and saving it to Google Sheets.  These links should guide you in the correct path:

- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [Google Apps Script Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script)

Then, you can use a [Time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to schedule the script to run daily.